# use a wildcard in text-based filter criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have a Journey using Salesforce Data as Entry Source.  For the object we are using, we want to filter out records that have certain words in a text field - but there is no filter operator for "Does not contain"... we have "Contains" and "Does not equal".  So I am wondering if it is possible to use a wildcard character in the filter criteria, e.g.

```
FIELDname Does Not Equal *temp*
```

or

```
FIELDname Does Not Equal %temp%
```

other suggestions?
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible, I'd suggest to pre-process your data using SQL and the LIKE operator.

Comment: If you dont get it done with "Contains" you are out of luck. Either you go with Jonas answer or you do something on SF side, like a formular field.

Comment: ok, thanks for the "second opinion"... and here's hoping for a "does not include" in the future ;)